# How to copy content from another site actively?

Tags: php, wordpress, code-reuse

I am new here and looking for some help to copy content from a specific page on another site.
I tried

```
$result get_file_contents('https://ncov.totok.ai/details');
echo print $result
```

something like.

Where I am trying to get.

I have a Wordpress website. because Wordpress does not allow us to use PHP code directly into posts and pages. therefore, I added a plugin called Insert PHP and some other to use their shortcodes into posts or page to run custom code.

when I save file and check preview, nothing shows there.
I would like to ask the professionals to advise the way to do it.

Result Page: [how to copy the active result from this page](https://ncov.totok.ai/details)

Comment: try this https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: output results ‘;

// Find all links foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $element) echo $element->href . ‘
‘; ?> but not sure about the page extension.